# How to run app without a desktop environment?

Tags: xorg, 20.04

I don't want to install a desktop environment, and I also don't want any login screen. I just want to launch X using *startx* command and then launch an app inside it.

I tried to install Xorg using *apt install xorg* but then I saw some GNOME packages in the dependencies. I installed it, rebooted my server and it now boots into vanilla GNOME.

How can I install Xorg without a desktop environment? Or at least, how can I disable all desktop environments and login screens after I install Xorg?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? No GNOME package should be a dependency of X.Org instead it could be a recommended package, Did you run command  with `--no-install-recommends`?

Comment: I'm using 20.04, I'll try to run it with it...

Comment: @Kulfy Ok, I tried it but there are still some GNOME packages, such as gnome-terminal and gnome-terminal-data. But these are the only GNOME packages I see. I'll try to install it...

Comment: X.Org has `x-terminal-emulator` as dependency. x-terminal-emulator is a virtual package and is provided by multiple packages such as konsole, XTerm and terminator. If you have one of them installed, GNOME Terminal won't even get installed.

Comment: How do I run a GUI app now. I saw startx && firefox in one quesion but then I saw sudo xinit firefox $* -- :1

Comment: Which GUI app are you using?

Comment: @Kulfy I want to run Chromium browser.

Comment: @Kulfy I tried to run startx and it says "xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused"

Comment: You may need to switch to other TTY or reboot the system.

Comment: @Kulfy I tried that but it didn't help. It worked after I installed xinit without the recommended packages.

Comment: Since I believe, now you've resolved your issue, I'd recommend you to post an answer. You can mark that accepted once 48 hours of posting the question have been passed.

Comment: I still haven't resolved it. I only see a blue screen with a cursor after I run startx. I tried startx && firefox but it didn't work.